# Minimum height for div or span with empty element

Tags: html, css, string

When I enclose within `span` or `div` a string that happens to be an empty string or includes only white spaces, that part does not have any height, and when that `span` or `div` is further embedded into something like a `table`, that cell does not have enough height, and looks wrong. How can I ensure that a `span` or `div` takes up at least the height of when the string has other characters? This is something like doing `\strut` in TeX. I can either insert something into the string, or adjust the css.

I tried, putting the following into the relavant css class, but the problem is that I have to manually adjust the string height (I am not sure if it is "1em". Probably not). What is the right way to do this?

> min-height : 1em;

Comment: If it's a SPAN, you're going to need to add "display:block;" to it to accept height values. By default, it's displayed inline. I would also recommend if this is inside a table to assign the min-height to the <tr> tag specifically and make the entire row the same height.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your `span` element needs to become a block element if you want to set its height. So set the style `display: block` or `display: inline-block` as appropriate.

```
span.item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

To set the height of an empty span, **I've found it best** to simply inject a `&nbsp;` rather than set a min-height. (**UPDATE**: per @sawa, rather than using a non-breaking space character, perhaps a more suitable character would take up *no* space, i.e. the unicode ZERO WIDTH SPACE character, `\200b`.)

```
span.item:empty::before {
  content: "\200b"; /* unicode zero width space character */
}
```

This will work for whatever the font size may be, and it avoids problems with the baseline not lining up with adjacent text. Look at the line that says "Huh?" below:

[image: how baseline fails]

http://plnkr.co/edit/GGd7mz?p=preview

(See similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29354766/516910)

Comment: `"\00a0"` (`&nbsp;`) takes up horizontal space. I think `"\200b"` (`&#8203;`) is better

Comment: @sawa Agreed, `"\200b"` give the presence of text while being completely invisible.

Comment: Octal escape sequences are deprecated. Use `\u200b` instead.

Comment: @PrasadSilva Hmmm... what's your source saying this is deprecated? The current CSS spec doesn't say anything about a leading "backslash u". That would just give you a literal "u". The spec says "backslash followed by 1-6 hex digits". See this railroad diagram: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#string-token-diagram  and  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#escape-diagram

Comment: Yea, my mistake. I was looking at this post trying to fix a strict mode error I got in JS while using the zero width space character. ES5 forbids octal syntax in strict mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't right: you don’t need enclosing quotes ("") around values in CSS.

Either use:

```
min-height: 1em; /* I am not sure if one can use em with height properties */
```

Or use:

```
min-height: 12px;
```

Comment: That was just my typo. Actually, It worked without the quotations, and `em` is available. I checked it with different values of `em`, and it worked. The problem is that I need to adjust it manually.

Comment: You can set the min property for table colums. Otherwise you have to manage it manually. Besides, it good behavior not to do anything on its own. You might have strange results otherwise :-)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to accept the comment part of your answer.